# Joomla "JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist" error during extension update

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I build a Joomla 3.x extension : https://github.com/Sagenda/joomla/

When I use the Joomla internal update system, I got this error :

JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist /home/synergie/public_html/synergie/contao/joomla30/tmp/install_5bd443ecad85c/joomla-0.7.1/ mod_sagenda_calendar.xml
Module %s: Could not copy files from the source.

[image]

How to I correct this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added extra spaces in between the filename tags so filenames became different. I have given the corrected one below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.8.13" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>Sagenda booking and scheduling calendar</name>
    <author>Iteration.info SARL</author>
    <version>0.7.1</version>
    <description>A Booking Calendar for your Joomla Website</description>
    <files>
        <filename>mod_sagenda_calendar.xml</filename>
        <filename>mod_sagenda_calendar_update.xml</filename>
        <filename module="mod_sagenda_calendar">mod_sagenda_calendar.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <folder>mashape</folder>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
    </files>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="sagendaToken" required="true" type="text" label="Token" description="Please paste here the token that you can found on your dashboard : https://sagenda.net/Dashboard" size="200" default="" />
                <field name="sagendaWeekStartsOn" type="list" label="Week start on" description="Please select which day your week should start on your calendar." size="200" default="1">
                    <option value="0">
                        Sunday
                    </option>
                    <option value="1">
                        Monday
                    </option>
                    <option value="2">
                        Tuesday
                    </option>
                    <option value="3">
                        Wednesday
                    </option>
                    <option value="4">
                        Thursday
                    </option>
                    <option value="5">
                        Friday
                    </option>
                    <option value="6">
                        Saturday
                    </option>
                </field>
                <field name="sagendaDateFormat" type="text" label="Date format" description="Define the format of date you want, &lt;br/&gt; YYYY-MM-DD for 1981-10-25 &lt;br/&gt; DD.MM.YY for 25.10.1981" size="200" default="DD MMMM YYYY" required="true" hint="Please enter a format" />
                <field name="sagendaTimeFormat" type="text" label="Time format" description="Define the format of time you want, &lt;br/&gt; HH:mm for 18:00&lt;br/&gt; hh:mm A for 06:00 PM" size="200" required="true" default="HH:mm" hint="Please enter a format" />
                <field name="note11" type="note" label="You will find the complete list of possible date and time format here : &lt;a href='https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/' target='blank'&gt;https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/&lt;/a&gt; " class="alert alert-info"/>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
    <updateservers>
        <server type="extension" name="mod_sagenda_calendar">
            https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sagenda/joomla/master/mod_sagenda_calendar_update.xml
        </server>
    </updateservers>
</extension>
```